# creating a ydn-db service for angularjs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, ydn-db, meanjs

I'm working on a project using [Meanjs](http://meanjs.org/) and ydn-db for indexeddb support.

So I'm trying to make a service in angular, but I just can't figure a way to include the js file properly. I've tried installing the lib in the following methods:

1. bower install ydn-db
2. bower install ydndb

   The first case, I could not find a suitable.js file like `ydn.db-isw-core-qry-dev.js`. Now the second would install the two minified versions which I could work, but I always get the  **ydn not found** error

Now by looking into the Developer's page http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/getting-started.html  I can see that he has a way of making the require in the AMD loader section, which I simply did not know how to use inside the service factory.
Here is what I'm trying to do inside the factory which by the way I don't think is best practices...
  And these are the error that I'm getting just by trying to load this...
How can I use this lib while still following best practices for angular or at least just to get it working without errors?

```
ldb undefined 
Object {db: Object, debug: Object}    

Uncaught ydn.error.ArgumentException: Unknown attribute "keypath"

angular.module(ApplicationConfiguration.applicationModuleName).factory('Localdb',['$resource','$q',
    function($resource,$q) {
        var deferred=$q.defer();
        require.config({
            baseUrl: '/content',
            paths: {
                ydn: 'scripts/ydn.db-isw-core-qry-dev'
            }
        });
            require(['scripts/ydn.db-isw-core-qry-dev'], function(ldb){
                console.log ('ldb',ldb);//this is undefined   
                var schema ={
                    stores:[
                        {
                            name:'process',
                            keypath:'_id',
                            indexes:[{
                                    name:'processId',
                                    keypath:'processId',
                                    unique:false
                                },{
                                    name:'processMeta',
                                    keypath:'processMeta',
                                    unique:false
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                };
                console.log(ydn);//this gets back ok but then the keypath error???
                deferred.resolve(new ydn.db.Storage('pdc',schema));
            });
            return deferred.promise;
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, to get your trouble. ydn-db repo do not have compiled js file, as require (I think) by bower. So it doesn't work. Just [download](http://dev.yathit.com/index/downloads.html) one of the js file and add to your html.

Also check out [ydn-db with angular example app](https://github.com/yathit/feature-matrix).

Comment: is there any way to make ydn work with requirejs? I'm also having null reference in the callback parameter when I try to load it

Comment: I've already try downloading the file and it gives me a cannot find KeyPath error... So right now Im using the ydndb bower aproach but still get a "ydn is not defined", plus I had to download the map which I don't think is the one that matches ydndb bower repository.. any ideas how to fix this ??

Comment: I will update bower support. Look like we are on the age of bower and don't know how to use a javascript file natively.

Comment: @KyawTun thanks for putting bower support on your backlog (that will be useful and easier to implement), anyway my point doesn't have anything to do with it, I'm just trying to get stared with your library and using require.js loading it in the same way you mentioned http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/getting-started.html the odd thing is that I get a null reference in th callback parameter, I'll post a question regarding to this matter.

Comment: ydn.db should be available in bower now. `bower install ydn.db`.

Comment: @KyawTun hi there thanks for your response at the end I downloadit a customise file cursor, idexeddb, query and events and added manually to the contents folder according to meanjs structure.. anyways can you  give me an idea on how to handle this other problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831368/promise-then-does-not-get-call?noredirect=1#comment38555166_24831368 Thanks for your support :D